Can I use "I can't help asking him" when I don't want to ask someone but I have to?

I can't help asking him.

Can I use this sentence if I don't want to ask him but I am in a situation in which I have to do so?
A friend of mine, who is more competent in English than I am, says "can't help ~ing" implies an internal, uncontrollable urge, but not an external obligation. Is she correct? If so, the answer to my question will be "no".
The following sentence motivated me to ask my questions in this post:

I can't help working even when I'm sick.

(The writer is a Japanese learner of English.)
And I would like to know whether the following sentence sounds natural to native speakers of English.

He can’t help studying English at least over 6 hours everyday.

(From a Website for Japanese learners of English.)
The Website says this sentence means "He has to/must study English at least over 6 hours every day".
[Edit]
It is obvious that "I can't help coding" means "I cannot stop myself from coding". I can't help coding teaches me nothing. TimR's excellent comment has satisfactorily resolved my questions.

Your friend is correct. If you don't want to ask him but the situation requires you to do so:  You have no choice but to ask him.

Thank you very much, @TimR.

@FumbleFingers. I don't understand at all why you think that thread is helpful for my problem. Maybe I should look for another forum that would be suitable for Japanese learners of English.

Like it says in that linked page: I can't help coding means you cannot stop yourself from coding. That's exactly what your friend means when she says "can't help ~ing" implies an internal, uncontrollable urge, but not an external obligation. This idiomatic usage often occurs in reflexive constructions, so dictionaries will usually define it as be unable to / cannot help oneself (idiom), which might not be so obvious for you to look up. But that's the Merriam-Webster definition for you.

...Note that I can't help working even when I'm sick isn't a good example for this idiom, because it's possible you have to work because you need the money and you won't get paid if you don't work. There's no such uncertainty with, for example, I can't help thinkig about work even when I'm on holiday.

...so your answer is No - it doesn't work for I can't help asking him. As Timr commented, what you could say there is I have no choice but to ask him, but the syntax of that might be strange for you. You may prefer I cannot avoid asking him. Or just I have to ask him (often pronounced haff). Or even I must ask him.

@FumbleFingers. What the linked page gives is essentially a dictionary definition of "can't help ~ing", but no more.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In English this would be better expressed as "I have no choice but to ask him".  If you say "can't help [doing something]" it generally means you have an uncontrollable urge to do something, or that you can't stop yourself from doing something.  So, it doesn't really have the meaning you want.

Thank you very much, @BillyKerr.

I have a feeling this may be a result of a translation for 仕方ない?

Thank you, @Andrew. せざるを得ない and 仕方がない are very common Japanese translations of "can't help ~ing".

@FumbleFingers. It is obvious that "I can't help coding" means "I cannot stop myself from coding". The page "I can't help coding" teaches me nothing. Anyway, TimR's excellent comment has answered my questions.


I can't help asking him.

The OP did not clarify why they think this involves external obligation.
I'll give two examples.
(1) You knew that a person did something which he denied.  You  preferred not to say it, hoping that he'd own up.  Finally you decided to confront him.
Here you can use can't help asking.
The force is an
internal one; there's no external
obligation.
This
is similar to
I can't help coding, which
refers to the speaker's inability to stop an internal urge to do coding.
(2) You managed not to
confront that person but are now required to provide evidence to the police.  We would say
I have no choice but to tell them.
but not can't help telling.

Thank you very much, @Seowjooheng Singapore.

Hi @Kaguyahime,  Yes, He can’t help studying English at least over 6 hours everyday is fine and is likely from internal motivation, similar to I can't help coding.

Thank you. The Website says it means "He has to/must study English at least over 6 hours every day".

If he needs to pass certain tests to get a job and the way to do it is to study that hard, then I'd say he has to/must study.

Thank you. Do you agree with my friend?

hi, @Kaguyahime, I have to do so itself can have various shades, including things largely
to do with internal urge.  For example, if you feel that it's only
morally right to do certain things.
If what you’ve described,
I don't want to ask him but I am in a situation in which I have to do so, is not one of such but is
similar to my police example, then
I'd not use can't help asking.   This is also
what your friend means by external obligation.

If I understood correctly, OP meant to ask:

"Does 'I can't help asking him' imply that I feel an uncontrollable urge to ask him, or can it also mean I am forced to ask due to external circumstances?"

When analyzing such phrases, it’s important to consider their meaning as a whole, rather than breaking them down into individual words.
1. Meaning of the Phrase:
To clarify the meaning of "can't help -ing," let’s consider two examples:

"I can't help working even when I'm sick": This means the speaker has such a strong internal drive or habit that they cannot stop working, even when unwell.
"I can't help smoking, even though I want to quit": This means the speaker is addicted to smoking and feels unable to stop, despite wanting to quit.

From these examples, "can't help -ing" reflects an internal, uncontrollable urge.
Thus, your sentence, "I can't help asking him," conveys the opposite of what you intend. Instead of implying external compulsion, it suggests that you always feel compelled to ask him due to an internal urge.
2. Alternate Ways to Express Your Intended Meaning:
To convey that you don’t want to ask but feel obligated, you could say:

"I have no choice but to ask."
"I have to ask him, even though I don't want to."
"I am going to ask him, although I don’t want to."

Edit - 1:.
The new sentence:
"He can’t help studying English at least over 6 hours every day"
Can be improved by:

Removing "over" (as it is redundant).
Adding "for" to clarify the duration.

The revised version becomes:
"He can’t help studying English for at least 6 hours every day."
The phrase "can't help ~ing" conveys a habit or an uncontrollable urge. Therefore, the correct meaning of this sentence is:
"He has a habit of studying English for at least 6 hours every day, and he does this of his free will "(not due to compulsion)

Thank you very much, @James Mathal. Probably, He can’t help studying English at least over 6 hours every day is a literal English translation of the Japanese sentence "彼は毎日少なくとも６時間以上英語の勉強をしなければならない。(= He has to/must study for at least 6 hours every day.)".

@Kaguyahime  "has to/ must" shows compulsion like someone is forcing him to study. But "can't help studying" means he enjoys/ likes to study.

Unfortunately, a typical Japanese translation of "can't help ~ing" is "～せざるを得ない", which normally means "have no choice but to ~".

"I can't help working even when I'm sick" is not usually an internal urge (as suggested) in western cultures that I know of. More commonly it is the result of an external economic imperative:  if I don't work just because I'm sick, I won't earn enough money to put food on the table, or pay the rent etc., particularly if I have casual or "at will" employment. In this sense westerners can use "can't help ~ing" with the same meaning as shown by @Kaguyahime:  "～せざるを得ない". As an example of the other meaning, "I can't help smiling when I see you" is an internal urge.

Thank you very much, @traktor.

@traktor Thank you for your insight! While "can't help ~ing" usually implies an internal urge, I agree there are exceptions where external pressures influence its use. However, without context, it’s likely to be misunderstood. In such cases, a different phrase might convey the meaning more clearly.

I can't help {doing something} or I can't help it or I can't help myself are used with situations where some psychological compulsiveness  or obsessiveness motivates the doing.

When I see a  picture sitting crooked on a wall, I can't help   straightening it, even if I'm not in my own house.

When the situation demands you  do something, even though you have no inclination to do it, we use "to have no choice but {to do it}" or "to have no other choice".

I had no choice but to mortgage the house. We needed money to pay those medical bills.


Thank you very much, @TimR. Is it in I can't help it fixed?

Yes, "it" is a fixed part of the expression. Another variant: "I can't help myself".

Many thanks, TimR.

I think this works when the gerund is an action that’s happening now or happens often.  Compare:
“I can’t help falling in love with you,” describes something going on now.
“I can’t help saying goodbye,” describes something that keeps happening repeatedly.
“I can't help telling you that I've begin to feel deserted,” (from a translation of Anne Frank’s diary) is a speech-act, an act that happens when it is said.
To me, “I can’t help asking him,” works if it’s something I do often.  But “*I can’t help asking him tomorrow,” sounds wrong.  It’s not an action happening right now or repeatedly, so the progressive aspect doesn’t suit it.
A formal and old-fashioned way of saying that I want to ask something once is,

I can’t help but ask [....]

The most common way of saying it is:

I have to ask [....]


Thank you very much, @Davislor.
